# How to mark text in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Please help me out with this code

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def click():

    t.insert(INSERT,"{}")
    t.mark_names()
    t.mark_set(INSERT,1.1)
    t.mark_gravity(INSERT,RIGHT)
b=Button(root,text="click",command=click)
b.pack()

t=Text(root)

t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So the insertion point will remain where it is. How can I make the insertion point to move along with the parenthesis assuming  I type and click that button again

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: Am new here, don't really know how to format code appropriately,  still trying to get it well

Comment: How do i do it please

Comment: Select the code, click the button that looks like `{}`.

Comment: OK thanks...I ll do just that next time. Do you have an idea about the code

Comment: Why not do it this time? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks, I've got to write another..but well formatted. Check out my profile

Comment: You shouldn't have asked a duplicate question just so you can format it better. What's wrong with editing this question?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this is the result you want:

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def click():
    t.insert(INSERT,"{}")
    t.mark_names()
    t.mark_set(INSERT,END)
    t.mark_gravity(INSERT,RIGHT)
b=Button(root,text="click",command=click)
b.pack()

t=Text(root)

t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I just set the position to END, everytime you click the button. That way, the next time you click the button, the brackets will be in order. This is the output:

[image: Output:]

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yeah, but I would love to put the insertion point between the curly braces example: {|}